# String thickness comparison

Tags: mechanical

I am currently working on a project which uses a massive array of strings linking little levers.  I am currently using the "thin" type string as it is the only type I have, but I am running into problems caused by actuation distance in the levers being absorbed by the strings stretching.

I am wondering if using "medium" or "thick" type LEGO strings would lessen this issue (without losing more actuation to sag from being heavier) but I have none to test with.  Has someone done, or can someone do a test of elasticity between the string types?

Comment: Lego string used in Technic is now wider and a silvery color, it does not stretch much to my knowledge (I own some) so maybe try that, if the problem persists, maybe it's due to vibrations in the string.
Here is a url to the longest length of the new string: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x77cc300&idColor=85 
and here is a link with the differnet strings lego make for sale: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=231